# Why is a value that I update in my model inside an MVC3 controller not rendered on the client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I have a controller action `UpdateCustomer(CustomerDto customer)` that returns a `PartialViewResult` with a model that is also a `CustomerDto`:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult UpdateCustomer(CustomerDto customer)
{
    CustomerDto updatedCustomer = _customerService.UpdateCustomer(customer);
    updatedCustomer.Name = "NotThePostedName";
    return PartialView("CustomerData", updatedCustomer);
}
```

In my view, I have the following line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

So far, so good. In my view I do an asynchronous post to this action method, the model binder does its work and I can update a customer in the database. Then I want to render the *updated* customer to the client. For example, I'd like to change the customer name in my controller. However, what gets rendered is *always* the properties from the posted `customer`, not the properties from `updatedCustomer`.

I decided to include the MVC3 source code in my project to see what really happens. It appears to be a feature (bug?) of MVC3 that it always takes the value from `ViewData.ModelState` instead of the value from `ViewData.Model`.

This happens at lines 366-367 of `System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions`:

```
string attemptedValue =
    (string) htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value",
    attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData)
        ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName)
        : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
```

As you can see, `attemptedValue` comes from `ModelState`. It contains the old value for `CustomerDto.Name` (the value that was posted to the controller action).

If this is a feature, why does it work this way? And is there a way to work around it? I would expect that if I update my model, the update gets rendered, not the old value I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well yes it's a feature (ModelState is always checked before actual Model), you can clear the ModelState, or update just the value you need:

```
ModelState["Name"].Value = updatedCustomer.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you have any idea why it's built this way? I have a view and provide it with a model but the properties from that model aren't rendered. It seems very counterintuitive.

Comment: I belive the assumption was, that if you are returning the same view in response to POST, you want the user the see the data he\she has entered.

Comment: To clear view data for partial views, just pass "additionalViewData" as  an empty object. this will override the view data for the partial view. View data is inherited from the parent view unless otherwise override this way. This may allow you to avoid setting the model state explicitly.