# MVC3 ajax update a field in strongly typed partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have some trouble play with MVC3.
I have a strongly typed partial view contains a form. it is embedded in a big page. I want to submit this partial view to controller and to update some fields. After the updating I expect the partial view embedded in the page being replaced with the html contains new values becuase the UpdateTargetId is declared, but it is not. Do not know if I can achieve that. Any help will be appreciated.
 The code as:

```
public ActionResult Employee(Employee em)
{
    var em1 = new Employee
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "xing yanguang",
        Code = "131324e12"
    };

    return PartialView(em);
}
```

The code in the partial view:

[image: employee partial view]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a value that I update in my model inside an MVC3 controller not rendered on the client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675213/why-is-a-value-that-i-update-in-my-model-inside-an-mvc3-controller-not-rendered)

Comment: Please check the duplicate link I have provided - it is the issue with ModelState (the partial view is ignoring your new model and takes values from ModelState)

Comment: yes, did duplicate with that got it. it works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
modify your partial view

```
//In Partial View 

 @model MvcApplication1.Employee

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            </td>
             <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  

Now in your parent view 



// In View.cshtml
    <div id="div_employee">
       @Partail("partailView",Model)
    </div>
       @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Employee", "PO", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "div_employee", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
       {
           <input type="submit" value="save" />
       }
```

In Controller

```
public string Employee(Employee em)
{
    var em1 = new Employee
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "xing yanguang",
        Code = "131324e12"
    };

    return RenderPartialViewToString("partailView",em1);
}


protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

In controller add one more method to get RenderHtml of partial view, by passing **PartailViewName** and **model** to RenderPartialViewToString  method it will return Htmlstring of view with updated values.