# Wrong default form values from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a backup variable for an account's username that I save through posts in a hidden field, `@Html.HiddenFor(u => u.backupUsername)`. This is the function the form posts to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(AccountModel newInfo)
    {
        validateUserInfo(newInfo);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            newInfo.updateToDatabase();
        }
        TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;
        TempData["SomeModel"] = newInfo;
        return RedirectToAction("Main");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Main()
    {
        if (TempData.ContainsKey("ModelState"))
        {
            ModelState.Merge((ModelStateDictionary)TempData["ModelState"]);
            return View("View", (SomeModel)TempData["SomeModel"]);
        }
    }
```

In `updateToDatabase()`, the backup username is updated to match the current one. I've set breakpoints and looked at the values during debug to confirm that this does happen and work.

However, as soon as `Update()` is called again, `newInfo.backupUsername` is back to what it was before anything had been changed. What am I missing here? Shouldn't the form's--and therefore the hidden field's--values get repopulated from the model passed in?

Comment: When you look at the HTML source, does the hidden element have the right value?

Comment: @asymptoticFault Nope, same unchanged, wrong value.

Comment: @asymptoticFault Yes, doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning another view after the POST request, ASP.NET MVC thinks validation has failed and displays the old values from the request. The changes in the model instance are ignored. You can read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx) for a detailed explanation.

Best solution would be to use [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) when the operation is succesful but if you think you don't need it, you can tell ASP.NET MVC to ignore the original values from the request.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(AccountModel newInfo)
{
    validateUserInfo(newInfo);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        newInfo.updateToDatabase();
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(newInfo); 
}
```

I can't easiest way would be implement Post-Redirect-Get would be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(AccountModel newInfo)
{
    validateUserInfo(newInfo);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        newInfo.updateToDatabase();
        TempData["newInfo"] = newInfo;       
        return RedirectToAction("Main");
    }
    return View(newInfo);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Main()
{
    var model = (TempData["newInfo"] as AccountModel) ?? new AccountModel();//or some other way to populate the model when it'not redirected from Update method.
    return View("View", model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've now changed the return to `RedirectToAction("Main")`, passing the model and ModelState to `Main()` through TempData, but the value of the hidden field is still unchanged. What should I use if I want to have the new values displayed?

Comment: @idlackage Can you post that method also?

Comment: @idlackage I think you need to store newInfo in TempData and retrieve it in Main method.

Comment: Whoopes sorry, that was a typo when I was renaming my variables for the post!

Comment: Can you debug and see you get the updated newInfo in Main method?

Comment: @idlackage Can you try the methods I posted?

Comment: I just tried this and it also goes well until the `return View()` statement; looking through the model's values in `TempData` shows that `backupUsername` is equivalent to `Username`, but apparently something crazy happens afterwards that causes `backupUsername` to be reset again. Would it make a difference if what I'm passing in is a ViewModel, and the form I'm working with is in a partial view that uses `MainViewModel.AccountModel`?

Comment: @idlackage Very strange.What do you see in ModelState for backupUsername?

Comment: Interesting, the `AttemptedValue/RawValue` has the unchanged backupUsername. I have absolutely no idea why/what this means, though...

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I have found the reasoning/answer. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675213/why-is-a-value-that-i-update-in-my-model-inside-an-mvc3-controller-not-rendered): all I had to do was clear the ModelState before validating/doing anything so that the old values would not be persisted.

Comment: I suggested this in my initial answer. It didn't work for you?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I actually didn't end up trying it at first because I wanted to keep the ModelState errors and didn't know on what ModelState.Clear() would do other than getting rid of those errors, and so stopped looking into it further. Now that you've told me about looking in the ModelState for values and returned my attention to it however, I understand it a lot better and see how it would have worked. So sorry and thanks!